# Filtering a list by current user's Department in Sharepoint Online

Tags: list, list-form

Im trying to filter a list by users department (Department field exists in the List). I've tried using the solution posted in a  similar query post (i.e : Filter List view/CQWP/DVWP by current users department) but it doesnt work.

Can any one help ?

regards